# Salesforce: Validation using two Picklist Fields

Tags: validation, picklist

I'm trying to create a validation rule formula in Salesforce, that uses two picklist fields. If the first is picked as New Account, and the Second is Not Selected, then a validation rule appears: Office Type is required!

First Pick Value List: field name: OnBoarding Setup = New Account

Second Pick List Value: field name: Office Type = Blank or Not Selected or Null

Any help would be greatly appreicate it.

Regards, C/

Answer (score 7):

Try this as the condition

```
ISPICKVAL(OnBoarding_Setup__c, 'New Account')) &&
(
    ISPICKVAL(Office_Type__c, 'Blank') ||
    ISPICKVAL(Office_Type__c, 'Not Selected') || 
    /* Add more values here if needed, join them with "||" ("logical OR") */
    ISPICKVAL(Office_Type__c, '')
)
```

Although I admit I'm not sure if your picklist really has the values like "Blank"...

Comment: You can create a validation rule to check for 'Blank' picklist values by using: 'ISPICKVAL(Office_Type__c, '')'

Comment: Thanks @RickyHewitt, forgot about this simpler option completely :)

Comment: Hi CGarcia! A follow-up after 1 month? :D If you have no more questions or issues with it - would you mind marking the answer as accepted so it goes "off the radar"?